# Jython swing supercall to class "extending" JTextField

Tags: swing, jython

I am trying to make a custom TextField similar to [the panel here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html). However if I try calling super for certain methods it goes into infinite recursion leading to the recursion limit (never had a more suiting question for stackoverflow ;) ), the methods are for example `paint` and `add` (those two I tried, I guess it is everything inherited).

Here is the important code excerpt:

```
class inputWithButtons(JLayeredPane):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setLayout(_textFieldWithButtons())

        self._fileField = JTextField()
        self.add(self._fileField, Integer(1))
        self.preferredSize = (0, 40) #TODO: why does minimumSize not work?



    def add(self, component, layer):  #recurses indefinitly
        super(inputWithButtons, self).add(component, layer)
        self.revalidate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is protected in their respective java class, you have to use the following syntax (Honestly hate this method)

```
self.super__
```

ex:

```
from javax.swing import JPanel

class panel(JPanel):
    def paintComponent(self, graphic):
        self.super__paintComponent(graphic)
        # Do something
```

[Source](http://sourceforge.net/p/jython/mailman/message/8856980/)

To call any other super class methods, you use this syntax:

```
SuperClassName.method(self, *args)
```

With [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-new-style-class):

```
super(panel, self).method(*args)
```

Comment: I cant test this since the source for this is out of my reach, but it sounds like the right answer.