# Extending a Jython base class with a Java class

Tags: java, python, oop, jvm, jython

I know it is trivially easy to extend a Java bass class with a Jython one, but what about the other way around?

Some preliminary tests tell me that the Java child class can't see the Jython one, at least at compilation time, which makes sense because the Jython class doesn't exist in a compiled state yet! Is there any work around though?

For context, I have a Jython base class which implement a lot of utilities which make heavy use of Python syntactic power, and implement the heavy, problem-specific algorithms in child classes. I would like like those lower classes to be in pure Java, simply for performance reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jython swing supercall to class "extending" JTextField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845209/jython-swing-supercall-to-class-extending-jtextfield)